# Kendo DataViz Widgets and UI Widgets on the same page

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

Is it possible to have Kendo UI widgets + DataViz widgets on the same page?
I wanted to have Grid(Popup Editing, Inline Editing etc.), Slider, AutoComplete, Rich Text Field and a Scatter Chart on the same page.
I have downloaded the latest trial package - kendoui.trial.2012.3.1114

I have added the files as below..

```
<link href="../../content/shared/styles/examples-offline.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="../../../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../content/shared/js/console.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/kendo.dataviz.min.js"></script>
```

But on adding "kendo.dataviz.min.js", other widgets seems to misbehave.
How to overcome this and have both UI widgets and DataViz widgets on the same page..???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used both UI widgets and dataviz widgets on the same page and faced no issue.

On a side note,Instead of including "kendo.web.min.js" & "kendo.dataviz.min.js" files, you can include "kendo.all.min.js" file alone that includes code for both UI widgets and dataviz widgets.

You can use "jsfiddle.net" to show your example that will help others in suggesting the root cause.